# Braintree default payment method is not updated when updating customer

Tags: braintree

I'm using BrainTree drop-in UI, and I'm generating a client token as follows:

```
token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate(customer_id: some_id, options: {make_default: true })
```

Then updating the customer through:

```
Braintree::Customer.update(
    some_id,
  payment_method_nonce: options[:payment_method_nonce]
)
```

However the selected credit card isn't set as the default one, as checking `customer.default_payment_method` always returns the same card. So any clue to update the default payment method when updating customer?

**Edit**

After some investigation, it seems when I add a new payment method, it is set as the default one, however when choosing a saved payment method, it is not set as default.

I ended up using the following code:

```
Braintree::PaymentMethod.create(
  customer_id: some_id,
  payment_method_nonce: options[:payment_method_nonce],
  options: {
    make_default: true
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

That's correct - the Drop-in UI as you've configured it will make newly-created payment methods the default, but will not do the same with an existing payment method selected by the customer for a particular transaction.

In order to get the result you're looking for, I'd suggest using the [credit card token from the transaction result object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/ruby#credit_card_details.token) to update the payment method as in [this example](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/update/ruby#make-default):

```
result = Braintree::PaymentMethod.update(
  "the_token",
  :options => {
    :make_default => true
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, however I'm not charging the customer directly but I'm saving the card for later use, I edited the post to include the final code I used to achieve this, please advise me if there is a better way.